# Apeax pageblock buttons showing space on left side of the panel

Tags: visualforce, visualforce-component, pageblocktable

I have a pageblock table

```
<apex:pageBlock id="PubListPanel" >
        <apex:pageblocktable value="{!AModel.List}" var="list">
        <apex:column width="28" rendered=......... >
<\apex:pageBlock>

<apex:pageBlockButtons rendered=.... id="pgbuttonsTop" location="top">
<apex:outputPanel id="pgbuttonsPanelTop">
```

My problem is that the page block buttons are displayed above the pagebloack table however it is keeping a considerable gap on the left hand side. Please tell me if there is something wrong with my code. Is there any way I can align the pageblockbuttons to the left hand side?[image]

Comment: Can you please provide a screenshot and a bigger code sample?

Comment: can you post a good screenshot on where the gap is and what are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `apex:pageBlockButtons` is used to create that button section on the top and/or on the bottom of the pageBlock. If you don't want that behavior, simply add the buttons to you page without using the `apex:pageBlockButtons` tag

```
<apex:pageBlock id="PubListPanel" >
        <apex:pageblocktable value="{!AModel.List}" var="list">
        <apex:column width="28" rendered=......... >
<\apex:pageBlock>

<apex:outputPanel id="pgbuttonsPanelTop"><apex:commandbutton .... /></apex:outputPanel>
```

Also, see [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_pageBlockButtons.htm) for more info.

Comment: you are correct, it is because of the pageblock button and if I remove it, then the buttons are being aligned to the left. I just want to know, why is the pageblockbutton keeping a lot of space on the left hand side and if it would be possible to remove it. I want to keep the apex:pageBlockButtons  tag @Fernando

Comment: @Rimii, the apex:pageBlockButtons has that large left margin because it is meant to accommodate the title of the apex:pageBlock. If you *really* want to make it display without that margin, you'll either have to give up the apex:pageBlockButtons tag or get creative with CSS